# Understanding category $\mathcal O^\mathfrak p$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am trying to get a “picture” of $\mathcal O_0^\mathfrak p$, so maybe you could correct what I think to have understood:

Let's consider $\mathfrak{sl}_3$, call the simple reflections $s, t$ and the longest element $w$. Let's consider the parabolic subalgebra given by $I=\{t\}$. The coset representatives of minimal length are $W^\mathfrak p=\{e, s, st\}$. The simple modules in $\mathcal O_0^\mathfrak p$ are those simples with highest weight $w.0$ such that $tw > w$; these are $L(e), L(s)$ and $L(st)$. What are Verma modules and projective covers in $\mathcal O_0^\mathfrak p$? These are the maximal quotients of the ordinary Verma modules and projective covers that contain only the composition factors listed above.

By taking the “forbidden” composition factors and modding out the submodule they generate (marked <s>like that</s>), I think I should get:

```
M(e):      L(e)
       L(s)    L(t)
       L(st)   L(ts)
           L(w)

M(s):      L(s)
       L(st)    L(ts)
           L(w)

M(st):     L(st)
           L(w)
```

and for the remaining projective covers, the following composition factors remain:

```
P(s):      L(s)
        L(st) L(e)

P(st):     L(st)
           L(s)
```

Are these indeed the images of these modules in $\mathcal O_0^\mathfrak p$? I am astonished that neither the inclusions of Verma modules nor the inclusions of projectives remain inclusions. Furthermore, I doubt that $P^\mathfrak p(s)$ has a non-simple socle.

You see, I haven't got a good picture of what's happening here, so I appreciate any hints for introductory texts on how to work with $\mathcal O_0^\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Hopefully I will have time to give a more full answer later. For now I recommend looking at the short description in my paper with Mazorchuk https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07008 as well as the references we give there (this is certainly not the best place to start, but it was one I could find without spending time searching right now).

Comment: Thank you for your link! I think what I understood when asking agrees with what I understand from §2.4 in your article. I have tried to what I think how I obtain $Z^\mathfrak p M(w)$ from $M(w)$. But still, this doesn't look like the correct modules.

Comment: I will need to take a closer look when I am back on a computer, but at first glance these looks ok. The Zuckerman functors are certainly not exact,  though whether these are the left- or right exact ones is something I don't know off-hand. I would guess that they are the right exact ones since these are the modules with "important" quotients which should be preserved. I should also note that the derived functors of the Zuckerman functors have been studied and used a fair bit by Mazorchuk among others, so once I can look up references I should be able to find something about this.

Comment: You can find some stuff about $\mathcal O ^{\mathfrak p}$ in [Humphreys: Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal O$](https://books.google.hr/books?id=8GCP4Ng6risC), chapter 9.

Comment: @rafaelm Thank you. Indeed example 9.5 addresses the Vermas of the ₃-case, which seem to be the modules I suggested. But am still uncertain about the projectives. Humphreys states that there is a parabolic Version of BGG reciprocity, which is not the case for the projectives I proposed. What is their correct shape, and how do I obtain it?

Comment: Indeed, your projectives are not right. The parabolic corresponds to the right cell consisting of $s$ and $st$ and the projective covers of the simples with these highest weights are self-dual by Theorem 6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2729 (it may take a bit getting used to the slightly different way of looking at things there, but it is well worth it).

Comment: I did a quick calculation in GAP with the KL bases and unless I miscalculated, you just need to add the top as the socle of each of your projectives to get the right thing, so you must have removed too much somehow. This also makes the parabolic BGG reciprocity work out correctly.

Comment: I tried to calculate the projectives in the way you have done here, and the issue is that it is not always easy to see from just writing up the composition factors like this which ones can be eliminated without eliminating things further down (when we have a layer with more than one summand at the bottom, it can easily happen that some submodule contains part of a higher layer without containing the entire bottom layer).

Comment: A final comment for now: I don't have time to check this myself right now, but it might be the case that the Zuckerman functors send Verma flags to parabolic Verma flags (even though they are not left exact). You could check if this is at least the case here to get an idea of whether it might hold in general (if it does, I am sure it will be mentioned somewhere, but I don't have time to search right now).

Comment: After thinking about my last comment for a while I "cheated" and asked Mazorchuk. It turns out that the Zuckerman functors need not send Verma flags to parabolic Verma flags and he had an example for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ where this was the case. So that will not be a way to understand how to apply the Zuckerman functors unfortunately.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, I didn't assume that to happen, fortunately. I'm still a bit irritated about the submodules since I tried to compute them in terms of path algebras of quivers, with lead to the submodules I canceled out mistakenly. So I have to think again how I did this, but maybe that is better placed in a follow-up question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the pictures we can draw like this (I assume you use the grading to decide which levels to put the simples on) do not tell the full story about which simples can go together to form submodules, as sometimes it is possible to "mix" parts of some of the layers and being able to tell which ones are possible is really tricky (if even possible in general). Probably the best ways to do these are applying projective functors for the ones corresponding to the right cell itself (possibly also for others, but there it is less clear what modules result in general).

Comment: Together with the parabolic BGG reciprocity, which then just needs you to calculate the parabolic Verma modules which are slightly easier.

Comment: Finally, as far as I recall, there is a notion of parabolic modules for the Hecke algebras with parabolic KL bases which should give you the full graded picture of composition factors in these parabolic modules. A good reference for that is probably Soergel's Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials and a combinatoric for tilting modules.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft My original approach was using path algebras. Although your comments (especially regarding self-duality and KL-polynomials) helped me very much understanding enough to continue my work, I am still concerned about what I did wrong in my path-algebra-approach. Since I still don't see the mistake, I have posed a [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2259014/309916).

Comment: I like that follow-up question. To finish off my attempt at an approach here: I was hoping that one could take the Verma flag on the projective and apply the Zuckerman functors to that to get the parabolic Verma flag on the parabolic projective. But unfortunately, even though the parabolic projectives do have parabolic Verma flags, these need not be just the images of the flag of the parabolic (as can be seen here on $P(st)$ where the $M(e)$ term from the Verma flag gets killed).

Comment: Although I did not try to find a description this way, it is good that you clarified that it wouldn't have worked. I'll keep this in mind.