# Modules in parabolic $\mathcal O^\mathfrak p$ in terms of path algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, quiver

As already brought up in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2252854/309916), I have some difficulties understanding the the modules in the parabolic category $\mathcal O_0^\mathfrak p$. Although I got a lot of comments that helped me understand the composition series of the modules in question, I still wonder why my original approach failed.

Assuming we work in $\mathfrak{sl}_3$, denote the simple reflections that generate the Weyl group by $s, t$ and let $W_\mathfrak p=\{e, t\}$ such that $W^\mathfrak p=\{e, s, st\}$. What is the projective cover $P^\mathfrak p(s)$ of highest weight $s$? By all the theory mentioned in the previous question, we know it has composition factors $L(s), L(st), L(e)$ and $L(s)$ in this order.

What I originally tried to do: We know that $\mathcal O_0$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Mod}_{\operatorname{End}(P)}$ where $P=\bigoplus_{w\in W}P(w)$ is a projective generator of $\mathcal O_0$. Now $\operatorname{End}(P)$ is isomorphic to the path algebra $A$ of the quiver given in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/ert/2003-007-15/S1088-4165-03-00152-3/S1088-4165-03-00152-3.pdf), section 5.1.2. Then $P(s)=e_2A$ is the quiver representation
$$
\begin{array}{c}
& \boxed{1\rightarrow 2}\\
\boxed{\begin{matrix}e_2 \\ 2\rightarrow1\rightarrow2\end{matrix}} && \boxed{3\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2}\\
\boxed{\begin{matrix}4\rightarrow 2\\4\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2\end{matrix}} && \boxed{\begin{matrix}5\rightarrow 2\\ 5\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2\end{matrix}}\\
& \boxed{\begin{matrix}6\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2\\6\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2\end{matrix}}
\end{array}
$$

What is the largest quotient of this containing only the simples to $e, s, st$, i. e. not containing the simple quiver representations $L(3), L(5), L(6)$ in its composition series? Well, let's see what is generated by the respective paths:

Under the relations mentioned in the article, $3\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2$ generates (let's omit the arrows):

- $5312 \propto 5212$,
- $65312 \propto 64212$
- $4312 \propto 4212$

and $52$ generates:

- $252 \propto 212$ (*)
- $652 \propto 642$

Hence the only paths in the representation that survive are $e_2, 42$ and $12$, corresponding to the simples $L(e), L(st)$ and $L(s)$. In particular, $212$ is lost due to (*), i. e. the socle $L(s)$ of the quotient is lost. This should not happen.

Question: Where in my computation of the submodule did I make a mistake? Why is the path $2\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2$ not contained in the submodule generated by $5\rightarrow 2$?

Comment: I will think about this approach to the problem next time I am on a computer. Maybe someone else who is more familiar with it can answer in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrangement of the weights into that hexagon shape in the cited paper "quivers and endomorphism rings" simple is other than expected: I assumed the corners to stand for

$$\begin{array}{c}
e\\
s\qquad t\\
st\qquad ts\\
w_0
\end{array}$$

However, the actual arrangement employed in that paper is
$$\begin{array}{c}
e\\
s\qquad t\\
ts\qquad st\\
w_0
\end{array}$$

With the same numbering, the "forbidden" weights $t, ts, w_0$ correspond to corners $3,4,6$. (*) Needs to be replaced by $424=0$, so this composition factor does *not* die.